# How to track # ajax links in Analytics?

Tags: jquery, ajax, seo, google-analytics

I have basic single page website with the normal Google Analytic code:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-##-##']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

However my links are like bookmarks - they basically slidedown the single page. My links when clicked are essentially pages but within the same template - they slide to reveal elements of content.

```
<a href="#section-3">about us</a>
```

**Is there a way I can update the Analytics tracker or somehow track links?** So in Analytics I will see people spent so much time on a page etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use jQuery for this.

Have the Analytics in your head, notice cleaner code:

```
<script>
    var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X'], ['_trackPageview']];
    (function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t),
    s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

And now place this in your footer where #main-navigation is an example of your UL > LI menu list. It will track all those pages.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $("#main-navigation a[href*='#']").on("click", function(){
            var $url = $(this)
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $url.attr('href')]);
        console.log('_trackPageview', $url.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Also note that; My code using protocol and cleaner JavaScript is up to 2000x faster.
http://jsperf.com/protocol-check-vs-hardcoded-string reference further http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet

Comment: +1 for the protocol and cleaner code, also user of `_trackPageView` rather than `_trackEvent`

Comment: Ok, M1th, read this article.. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide 
the "_trackPageview" uses when you tracking a goals.. e.g. just the Url... He need to see what the link was clicked.. and it is for "_trackEvent", for Event tracking. It Will appear in Event Overview in Analytics.

Comment: But the trackPageview will not show people playing audio?? @MaksymH.

Comment: @M1th, what audio are you talking about? I meant, that if somebody wants to track his link clicks or any of jQuery events and Also look the info regards this event - the best way is to track events (using _trackEvent), otherwise if he wants just see the what page has somebody seen, of course page traking(_trackPageview) will work. So your answer is also corret.. just depends on what TheBlackBenzKid wanted to see.

Answer (score 5):

Try this. In the HEAD place this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-##-##']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

In the FOOTER or in any other place - this:

```
jQuery(function($){

  $("a[href*='#']").on("click", function(){
        var $url = $(this);

        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ajaxLink', $url.text(), $url.attr('href')]);
        console.log('_trackEvent', $url.text(), $url.attr('href'));
  });
});​
```

And the HTML should be #Id reference to links. Such as:

```
<a href="#home-page">Home</a>
<br />
<a href="#about-us-page">About Us</a>
```

I used [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for learn it.

UPD: Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/K2PcL/

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you give me an example with the about us page, where would I write "about us" and also, does the Analytics code then need to be declared at the top of my page and I am guessing I need jQuery for that code of yours?

Comment: updated answer.. about jQuery - no, you can rewrite that code to any other library or use just plain javascript (but I would recommend use jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add page tracking to an onclick event.  Try changing your links to something like this:

```
<a href="#section-3" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/AboutUs']);”>about us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `push` the information `into the gaq array`.

[Everything you need to know is found here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)